# Typescript modules in client side - What is the best way?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I am building a web application.
I use typescript for the client side and golang for the server side.
I use typescript 3.9.2.

I want to compile the `.ts` files to `.js`, and use modules.
The default compiling compile it to *CommonJS* module loader.
Then in the browser it has some `exports.__...` in the second line.
I searched and it basicly said it want a variable called exports, which I don't have. In this case, I don't like the main solution to define a mock exports in other script tag.

I changed the `compilerOption` to `"module":"ES6"`
and then it compile and loaded well (after changing the type of the script to module), but the browser can't find the module i want to import.

The code goes like this:

use.ts

```
import * as fun from 'funcs'
let bar =  fun.foo()
```

funcs.ts

```
export function foo() :boolean{
return true;
}
```

use.js

```
import * as fun from 'funcs'
var bar =  fun.foo()
```

funcs.js

```
export function foo(){
return true;
}
```

And now the browser can't find `/funcs`, which it needs for the `use.js`. When i change manualy the first line in `use.js` to

```
import * as fun from 'funcs.js'
```

It works.

What can i do to make everything automatic?
What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES Module imports need to have the `.js` extension, but Typescript's modules don't and right now there does not appear to be a built-in option to add them automatically, but somebody did write [a script](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577#issuecomment-310426634) to add the extensions to the imports, or you can add them to the imports manually.

There is some [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35148) on the TypeScript Github about this and related issues. They are considering adding a module resolution option to the compiler for the browser.